# How to run a redis cluster with Sentinel

Tags: redis, redis-sentinel, redis-cluster

Since scaling and high availability are usually different concepts (Unless you opt for a load balancing fault tolerance scheme), I hoped Redis would support both. However to my understanding, we cant mix Redis cluster with Sentinel? If so how do I create a deployment which will have multiple partitions and is also managed by Sentinel?
Is there a guide that describes how this is done?

Answer (score 0):

Redis' cluster does its own failover, hence Sentinel is unneeded when operating in cluster mode: http://redis.io/topics/cluster-spec#availability

Comment: I've already tried cluster and it worked well, but I didn't try all failure scenarios. However Redis document it self recommends Sentinel for high availability. Not sure which one to use.

Comment: Sentinel is for standalone, single instance, non-clustered (as in sharding) deployments - i.e. master-slave(s) replication.